# My Libgdx generated project won't run as a desktop application

Tags: java, libgdx

My libgdx project won't run all I did was set up eclipse like they specify on the Libgdx wiki. I used their latest Jar(not the nightly) to generate the project and then I followed the instructions and imported it as a Gradle project. When I attempted to run the desktop project I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat(LwjglGraphics.java:321)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:215)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Here is line 321 from LwjglGraphics.java:
throw new GdxRuntimeException("OpenGL is not supported by the video driver: " + glVersion.getDebugVersionString(), ex3);
So maybe your video card doesn't support OpenGL 3?

Comment: No I checked and it supports OpenGL 3.

Comment: Can you try on another computer?